I work 3-4 days a week, on an 8-week schedule. Is there a quick way to add this to Google Calendar?
I work 3-4 days a week, on an 8-week schedule. The days vary weekly during that schedule, but the schedule repeats after 8 weeks.
Is there a quick way to add this to Google Calendar?
Can I create an 8-week repeating schedule?

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?

You still need to create a single version of your 8-week schedule but for each shift you create, select  Custom recurrence and then set it to 8 weeks.
Whatever differences there are across the first 8 Weeks will then be mirrored for future recurrences 8 weeks later, then 8 weeks after that, and so on.



Thanks for that. It more that its 3 days this week, 4 the next etc, and 8 weeks later the cycle starts again, so its messy........ Edited to add: I've just realised what you;re saying. Genius, thanks

Sorry edited my answer to be more clear.
